# Java - letter substitution not working

Tags: java, string, substitution

I was reading a book on cryptology and thought it would be a cool idea to write a small program that encodes and decodes a message.

I started out with a simple substitution cipher which would substitute a letter with a different letter, shifted a certain set amount. IE. one example would be: a->c, b->d, etc. just shifted by 2.

My code doesn't seem to be substituting the letters correctly. It always outputs the same thing I input, even thought the Key is set. Here is my code:

```
public class Keyshift {

public static int Key = 0;

public static void selectKey(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    int a = in.nextInt();
    Key = Key + a;
}

public static void encode(){

    String input = "";
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    input = in.nextLine();

    String[] inputLetters = input.split("");
    String[] output = new String[inputLetters.length];

    String dictLowercase = new String("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    String dictUppercase = new String("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
    String[] dictLowerArray = dictLowercase.split("");
    String[] dictUpperArray = dictUppercase.split("");


    for(int i=0;i<inputLetters.length;i++){
        for(int c=0;c<25;c++){
            if (inputLetters[i]==dictLowerArray[c]){
                output[i] = dictLowerArray[((c+Key) % 26)];
            }
            else if (inputLetters[i]==dictUpperArray[c]){
                output[i] = dictUpperArray[((c+Key) % 26)];
            }
            else {
                output[i] = inputLetters[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Your encoded message is: ");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));   
    //System.out.println(Key);
}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    selectKey();
    encode();
}

}
```

Comment: In all actuality, if you converted everything to `char`, you could just add your offset in, since a `char` is an unsigned `int`.  You'd have to handle the wrapping yourself, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        String dictLowercase = new String("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        String dictUppercase = new String("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        char[] dictLowerArray = dictLowercase.toCharArray();//Use toCharArray
        char[] dictUpperArray = dictUppercase.toCharArray();
        char[] inputLetters = input.toCharArray();
        char[] output=new char[inputLetters.length];
        for(int i=0;i<inputLetters.length;i++){
            for(int c=0;c<25;c++){
                if (inputLetters[i]==(dictLowerArray[c])){
                    output[i] = (char) (dictLowerArray[c]+Key % 26);//Logic Issue
                }
                else if (inputLetters[i]==(dictUpperArray[c])){
                    output[i] = (char) (dictUpperArray[c]+Key % 26);
                }
                else {
                      output[i] = inputLetters[i];//If not alphabets
                }                
            }
          }
```

- Go for `char` manipulation rather than `String` for convinience.
- Use `.toCharArray()` instead of `split`
- You can directly use `character+Key % 26` on character.

Answer (score 1):

First try to compare to `String`s with `equals` and not `==`.
Moreover, you failed to specify any `break` point, in case you found something has been modified. Say, the first character of `inputLetters` matches with first letter of `dictLowerArray`, now the iteration again goes inside the second loop, this time only the last `else` block gets executes and the same value, as in `inputLetters` gets copied to the `output` array.

Try this loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<inputLetters.length;i++){
        for(int c=0;c<25;c++){
            flag = false;
            if (inputLetters[i].equals(dictLowerArray[c])){
                output[i] = dictLowerArray[((c+Key) % 26)];             
                break;
            }
            else if (inputLetters[i].equals(dictUpperArray[c])){
                output[i] = dictUpperArray[((c+Key) % 26)];
                break;              
            }
            else {
                flag = true;
            }
        }
        if (flag) {
            output[i] = inputLetters[i];
        }
    }
```